# DateTime conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to run the following simple SQL Query that selects data between two dates. The dates come from the following DateTimePickers: `DTP_From`, `DTP_To`

```
        DateTime startDate = DTP_From.Value.Date;
        DateTime endDate = DTP_To.Value.Date;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = con;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From Report_Sales where Date >= '" + startDate + "' AND Date <= '" + endDate + "'";
```

When the query is executed I get the following error:

> datetime conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How can I run the above query error free?

Comment: I would like to prefer use "Between" keyword instead of >= and <= operator

Comment: convert date into 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' format. and make sure the time of start date must be 00:00 and 23:29 for endDate otherwise some record will not be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameterize your query to avoid issues like this.

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From Report_Sales where Date >= @startDate AND Date <= @endDate";
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't follow Grant Winney's excellent advice to parametise your queries, which will also help you avoid other nasties; to include `DateTime` data into a Transact-SQL query it needs to be formatted using the ISO 8601 style:

> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnn[Z]

ie

```
SELECT *
FROM Report_Sales
WHERE Date >= '2014-04-18T21:26:01Z'
AND Date <= '2014-04-18T22:26:01Z'
```